# Unsupported operand type(s) TypeError in if block

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a function which is terminating with a TypeError and I'm not sure why:

```
#under 4 million

def fib(a, b):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b <= 4000000:
        a, b = b, (a+b)
        print a

#always call it with "fib(0, 1)"

fiblist = [fib(0, 1)]
print fiblist
#now for the function that finds the sum of all even fib's

total = 0
for i in fiblist:
    if i%2 == 0:
        total = total + i
        print total
```

here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ProjectEuler\ProjectEuler2.py", line 19, in <module>
    if i%2 == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
>>>
```

I appreciate any help you may provide. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`fib(a, b)` does not return anything - instead of returning a value, it prints it. If a function does not say to return anything, Python makes it `return None` implicitly.

Therefore, `fiblist = [fib(0, 1)]` is `[None]`.

Clearly, `None%2` is meaningless.

You should rewrite `fib(a, b)` to be a generator and to `yield` its results. Then you can iterate over it, in a similar fashion to iterating over `range()`, `xrange()`, lists and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the `fib` function, make it return something. Also, notice that you don't have to pass any parameters to it:

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    lst = []
    while b <= 4000000:
        a, b = b, (a+b)
        lst.append(a)
    return lst
```

Also fix this line:

```
fiblist = fib()
```

Now `fiblist` will contain actual numbers, and you can safely iterate over it. That'll fix the error you were experiencing!